# como sumar 2 propiedades de 2 objetos diferentes en js (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo estos 3 objetos

```
const leagues = [
  { id: 1, country: 'England', name: 'Premier League' },
  { id: 2, country: 'Germany', name: 'Bundesliga' },
  { id: 3, country: 'Netherlands', name: 'Eredivisie' },
  { id: 4, country: 'Spain', name: 'La Liga' },
  { id: 5, country: 'Italy', name: 'Serie A' },
  { id: 6, country: 'Portugal', name: 'Liga NOS' },
  { id: 7, country: 'France', name: 'Lige 1' }
]

const teamsByLeague = [
  { teamId: 12, leagueId: 5 },
  { teamId: 6, leagueId: 3 },
  { teamId: 2, leagueId: 5 },
  { teamId: 3, leagueId: 4 },
  { teamId: 4, leagueId: 2 },
  { teamId: 8, leagueId: 1 },
  { teamId: 10, leagueId: 6 },
  { teamId: 5, leagueId: 1 },
  { teamId: 7, leagueId: 5 },
  { teamId: 9, leagueId: 1 },
  { teamId: 11, leagueId: 2 },
  { teamId: 1, leagueId: 4 },
  { teamId: 13, leagueId: 7 }
]

const winsByTeams = [
  { teamId: 10, wins: 2 },
  { teamId: 6, wins: 4 },
  { teamId: 5, wins: 5 },
  { teamId: 1, wins: 13 },
  { teamId: 7, wins: 3 },
  { teamId: 4, wins: 5 },
  { teamId: 8, wins: 3 },
  { teamId: 2, wins: 7 },
  { teamId: 9, wins: 1 },
  { teamId: 3, wins: 5 },
  { teamId: 11, wins: 1 },
  { teamId: 12, wins: 2 },
  { teamId: 13, wins: 1 }
]
```

y tengo que saber el total de wins por league, osea sumar los wins del objeto 3 que están relacionados al objeto 1 a través del objeto 2.

He ocupado funciones como .find

```
(wins: (winsByTeams.find(win => win.teamId === team.id)).wins)
```

Para encontrar las id que sean igual, pero me pregunto si hay alguna funcion especial para sumar los wins del 3 objeto sin transformarlos en arreglo a través de .map

```
( const ligasOrdenadas = leagues.map((leagues) => ({
        name: leagues.name,
        winsTotal: (winsByTeams.find(win => win.teamId === leagues.id)).wins        

}));)
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar ejemplos del resultado que esperas? Para clarificar la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como siempre, todo es aplicar *divide y vencerás*:

- Dada una liga, filtras los IDs de los equipos que pertenecen a dicha liga:

  ```
  const teamIds = teamsByLeague
       .filter(team => team.leagueId ===leagueId) //nos quedamos los equipos de la liga
       .map(team => team.teamId); // y cogemos sus IDs
  ```
- Una vez que tenemos los equipos, sumamos sus victorias:

  ```
  return winsByTeams
       .reduce((acc,tw) => teamIds.includes(tw.teamId) ? acc + tw.wins: acc, 0);
  ```

  Que también se podría escribir como:

  ```
  return winsByTeams
       .filter(tw => teamIds.includes(tw.teamId))
       .reduce((acumulador,team) => acumulador + team.wins, 0);
  ```

Y todo junto queda así:

```js
function getWinsByLeague(leagueId) {

  const teamIds = teamsByLeague
    .filter(team => team.leagueId ===leagueId) //nos quedamos los equipos de la liga
    .map(team => team.teamId); // y cogemos sus IDs
  console.log('Equipos de la liga',leagueId,':',teamIds.toString());
  
  // sumamos las victorias de los equipos si su ID está en la lista obtenida
  return winsByTeams
    .filter(tw => teamIds.includes(tw.teamId))
    .reduce((acumulador,team) => acumulador + team.wins, 0);
}

const leagues = [
  { id: 1, country: 'England', name: 'Premier League' },
  { id: 2, country: 'Germany', name: 'Bundesliga' },
  { id: 3, country: 'Netherlands', name: 'Eredivisie' },
  { id: 4, country: 'Spain', name: 'La Liga' },
  { id: 5, country: 'Italy', name: 'Serie A' },
  { id: 6, country: 'Portugal', name: 'Liga NOS' },
  { id: 7, country: 'France', name: 'Lige 1' }
]

const teamsByLeague = [
  { teamId: 12, leagueId: 5 },
  { teamId: 6, leagueId: 3 },
  { teamId: 2, leagueId: 5 },
  { teamId: 3, leagueId: 4 },
  { teamId: 4, leagueId: 2 },
  { teamId: 8, leagueId: 1 },
  { teamId: 10, leagueId: 6 },
  { teamId: 5, leagueId: 1 },
  { teamId: 7, leagueId: 5 },
  { teamId: 9, leagueId: 1 },
  { teamId: 11, leagueId: 2 },
  { teamId: 1, leagueId: 4 },
  { teamId: 13, leagueId: 7 }
]

const winsByTeams = [
  { teamId: 10, wins: 2 },
  { teamId: 6, wins: 4 },
  { teamId: 5, wins: 5 },
  { teamId: 1, wins: 13 },
  { teamId: 7, wins: 3 },
  { teamId: 4, wins: 5 },
  { teamId: 8, wins: 3 },
  { teamId: 2, wins: 7 },
  { teamId: 9, wins: 1 },
  { teamId: 3, wins: 5 },
  { teamId: 11, wins: 1 },
  { teamId: 12, wins: 2 },
  { teamId: 13, wins: 1 }
]



leagues.forEach(l => console.log('La liga',l.name,'tiene',getWinsByLeague(l.id),'victorias'));
```