# Como crear un objeto donde las claves sean los nombres de otro objeto

Tags: javascript, nodejs

si tenemos los objetos

```
const leagues = [
  { id: 1, country: 'England', name: 'Premier League' },
  { id: 2, country: 'Germany', name: 'Bundesliga' },      
  { id: 3, country: 'France', name: 'Lige 1' }
]    

const teams = [
  { id: 1, country: 'Spain', name: 'Real Madrid C.F.' },
  { id: 2, country: 'Italy', name: 'A.C. Milan' },
  { id: 3, country: 'France', name: 'Olympique Marseille' }

]
```

Y quiero crear

```
const leaguesPeorEquipo = leagues.map((ligas) => ({
    name: ligas.name,
    country: ligas.country
}));
```

pero en vez de name: como Key quisiera poner team.name ya que ahi esta la el nombre del equipo que quiero como Key para luego asignarle los valores un nombre

Comment: Como te respondí [antes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226034/como-sumar-2-propiedades-de-2-objetos-diferentes-en-js-nodejs/226040#226040), *divide y vencerás*: elige una liga y quédate con su nombre. Entonces busca a los equipos de esa liga. Entonces quédate con el que menos victorias tenga. Repite los tres pasos para cada liga. No voy a ponerte todo el código de nuevo porque no veo que esta vez te hayas esforzado en buscar tú mismo la respuesta.

Comment: Bienvenido. Estaría bien que simplificaras la pregunta todo lo posible, no hace falta poner tantos datos en los objetos. También te agradecería que primero intentes hacerlo tú y nos muestres qué has probado y no te funciona. Básicamente estás pidiendo a la comunidad que te lo resolvamos todo, poniendo la solución donde pone //CODE HERE. No gracias.

Comment: Estimados muchas gracias, haré lo que me dicen.

Answer (score 0):

```
function leaguesWithTeamWithLestWins() {
    let object = {};

    leagues.forEach(league => {

        const teamIds = teamsByLeague
            .filter(team => team.leagueId === league.id) //nos quedamos los equipos de la liga
            .map(team => team.teamId); // y cogemos sus IDs

        const wins = winsByTeams
            .filter(tw => teamIds.includes(tw.teamId))
            .reduce(function(prev, curr) {
                return prev.wins < curr.wins ? prev : curr;
            });

        object[league.name] = teams.find(team => team.id == wins.teamId).name;

    });

    return object;
}
```

gracias Pablo Lozano

Comment: Esto es una respuesta?